# Access object properties like array for properties that are objects themselves

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I hope you are doing well!

So I have the following Object

```
const myObject = {
   firstName:'fname',
   lastName:'lname',
   role:{
     roleID:1,
     description:'Admin'
   },
   phone: '12345',
   email:'example@gmail.com'
}
```

and I want to access the properties in this method

```
myObject['phone']
myObject['email']
```

in Order to display them in a table whose order of columns can be changed.

So my Table Column Object looks like this

```
const TABLE_COLUMNS=[{Header:'Phone',accessor:'phone'},{Header:'Email',accessor:'email'},...]
```

but when it comes to columns like name and role, name represents the concatenation of firstName and lastName, and role can only be accesses by myObject.role.description and not directly.

Is there any way I can access the Object Properties in the method I am using at the moment?

(A method I am contemplating to use is to add a function property in my column header object and have it display them like I want but I can't save a function in a mySQL database and my columns will most probably be saved there)

Comment: You'd have to use a function for that property. Something like this: `accessor: (row) => row.role.description` and `accessor: (row) => row.firstName + row.lastName`. You can allow the frontend component to dictate this part and get rest of the things from the DB.

Comment: @adiga the problem with this method is that the order of the columns I receive from the backend is not the same since the User has the ability to change the order of columns to be displayed in the table

Comment: You'd have to set this in front end code. Including the Header or some sort of identifier for each column. You can save the order of columns and other details to backend.

Comment: FWIW: While there's likely a better solution here, it is possible to serialize a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) as a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) containing [ES module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) source text and then later [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) it: https://tsplay.dev/wgAAym

Comment: @jsejcksn The downside of that is you can't guarantee that the function is pure, and it's hard to verify. I'd rather recommend to either have a list of available functions identified by name, or to build a very simple interpreter for the pure logic (containing operations such as concatenation and property access).

Comment: @Bergi I think I'll just save an object in the frontend holding the functions and have the key the same as that of the accessor so I can access the function ```{function["name"](row)}```